# rbind all data frames with common names based on list using lapply

Tags: r, lapply, rbind

I have several data frames named as such:

```
orange_ABC
orange_BCD
apple_ABC
apple_BCD
grape_ABC
grape_BCD
```

I need to `rbind` those that have the first part of their name in common (orange, apple, grape), and name the new data frames as such. I'm accessing the names from a list of data frames `names(fruitlist)` (from which I made the aforementioned data frames) and have tried using `lapply` with `function(x)` with no luck. I'm somewhat new to R, so think I'm making a simple mistake when it comes to dynamically naming the new data frame...

```
lapply(names(fruitlist),
       function(x){
         frame_nm <- toString((names(fruitlist[x])))
         frame_nm <- do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern=paste0((names(splitlist[x])),"*"))))
})
```

I've tried the standalone line on one type of "fruit" and it seems to work:

```
test_DF <- do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern="apple*")))
```

EDIT: I realize I forgot to mention that the example list of 6 data frames were created dynamically, so I can't simply generate a list of them. However, I do have a list of the "fruits", and all possible the ends of the new data frame names are known ("_ABC" and "_BCD").

Comment: Based on your edits, I made some changes that may do what you need, based on the presence of your data frames in the global environment.

Answer (score 1):

If your `fruitlist` is a named list of data frames, maybe this will suit.

First, get the like names into their own list:

```
fruit.groups <- split(names(fruitlist), 
                      sapply(strsplit(names(fruitlist), split = "_"), "[[", 1))

> fruit.groups
$apple
[1] "apple_ABC" "apple_BCD"

$grape
[1] "grape_ABC" "grape_BCD"

$orange
[1] "orange_ABC" "orange_BCD"
```

Then, use `lapply` to `rbind` by group:

```
fdf <- lapply(fruit.groups, function(x){
  out <- do.call(rbind, fruitlist[x])
  out$from <- gsub("(\\..*)", "", rownames(out))
  rownames(out) <- NULL
  return(out)
})

> fdf$apple
  a  b      from
1 1 11 apple_ABC
2 2 12 apple_ABC
3 3 13 apple_ABC
4 4 14 apple_ABC
5 1 11 apple_BCD
6 2 12 apple_BCD
7 3 13 apple_BCD
8 4 14 apple_BCD
```

Fake data:

```
namelist <- paste(fruit = rep(c("orange", "apple", "grape"), 2), 
                  nums =  rep(c("_ABC", "_BCD"), each =  3), sep = "")

fruitlist <- llply(namelist, function(x){
  assign(as.character(x), data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 11:14))
})
```

**EDIT:**

From the edits to your question above:

If you have the fruits and suffixes, use `expand.grid` to get all possible combinations (assuming that all combinations will refer to the dynamically generated data frames).

```
fruits <- c("orange", "apple", "grape")
suffixes <- c("_ABC", "_BCD")
fullnames <- apply(expand.grid(fruits, suffixes), 1, paste, collapse = "")
```

Using that list of names, use `mget` to generate a list of the present dataframes.

```
new_fruit_df_list <- mget(fullnames)
```

Then, the code from above should work, modified here to reflect the name changes:

```
fruit.groups <- split(names(new_fruit_df_list),
                      sapply(strsplit(names(new_fruit_df_list), split = "_"), "[[", 1))

fdf <- lapply(fruit.groups, function(x){
  out <- do.call(rbind, new_fruit_df_list[x])
  out$from <- gsub("(\\..*)", "", rownames(out))
  rownames(out) <- NULL
  return(out)
})
```

Have a look at the head of each, with the added column (remove if you don't want it) showing the name of that row's original data frame.

```
> lapply(fdf, head, 2)
$apple
  a  b      from
1 1 11 apple_ABC
2 2 12 apple_ABC

$grape
  a  b      from
1 1 11 grape_ABC
2 2 12 grape_ABC

$orange
  a  b       from
1 1 11 orange_ABC
2 2 12 orange_ABC
```

Answer (score 1):

As suspected, the proposed way of assigning values to objects does not work. Moreover, care has to be taken when using `ls()` and `mget()` for listing and accessing named objects within a function, because they do not automatically ascend to parent environments and only "see" variables in the local scope unless told otherwise. This applies to R version 3.4, older versions may behave differently.

1. Creating named objects.

   In order to create new objects in the global environment, use `assign()` (already suggested in Luke C's answer):

   ```
   > assign("foo", "some text")
   > foo
   [1] "some text"
   ```

   Placing code inside a function induces a local scope. Explicitly specifying the global environment allows setting global variables:

   ```
   > set_foo <- function (x) { assign("foo", x, envir=globalenv()) }
   > set_foo("other text")
   > foo
   [1] "other text"
   ```

   Note that omitting the `envir` argument would leave the global environment unaffected.
2. Use of `ls()`/`mget()` within a local function.

   By default, this only lists names from the current (local) environment of the that function, which only sees the argument `x` in the example code given in the question. Similar to above, a quick fix is to specify the global environment explicitly by adding the argument `envir=globalenv()`. The same applies for `mget()`.

Since no MWE was provided, I am taking the liberty of adapting the "fake data" example code provided in Luke C's answer.

```
# Populate environment
namelist <- paste(fruit = rep(c("orange", "apple", "grape"), 2), 
                  nums =  rep(c("_ABC", "_BCD"), each =  3), sep = "")
for(x in namelist)
  assign(x, data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 11:14))

# The following re-generates the list of fruits used above
grouplist <- unique(unlist(lapply(strsplit(namelist, "_"), function (x) { x[[1]] })))
# Group and rbind by prefix, suppressing output
invisible(lapply(grouplist,
       function(x) {
         grouped <- do.call(rbind,
           mget(ls(pattern=paste0(x,"_*"), envir=globalenv()),
             envir=globalenv()))
         assign(x, grouped, envir=globalenv())
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
file_groups <- ls()[grep(".*_.*", ls())]
file_groups <- gsub("(.*)_.*", "\\1", file_groups)
df_list <- lapply(file_groups, 
                  function(x){ do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern = paste0(x, "*"))))})
```